# iText, loading an existing PDF and adding text to it

Tags: java, itext

I have an existing PDF, a simple 2 page form. I need to load the PDF, and in relevant pages in the form, insert text so that it's unique to each person that downloads the PDF.

My initial idea was the load the PDF, and on page one simply overlay the text in the relevant place, however when I try the code below, all this does is add the text to the end of page 1, rather than at the top where I'm telling it to position it.

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputFile);

        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

        for(int i=1; i<= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){
            PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.getOverContent(i);

            if (i == 1) {
                //Text over the existing page
                BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                content.beginText();
                content.setFontAndSize(bf, 18);
                content.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "This is some text " + i, 0, 0, 0);
                content.endText();
            }
        }
```

Could someone advise where I might be going wrong please?

Comment: A watermark wouldn't do?

Comment: Position `0, 0` is at the bottom of the page, so why do you expect the content to be at the top of the page? Your question doesn't make any sense. Also: you're using an old version of iText. `PdfStamper` doesn't exist anymore in iText 7.

Comment: I've not used iText before so sorry if I've mis-understood it. I assumed like most things and similar PHP libraries that 0, 0 was top left.